# approximating categories with continuous functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am wondering about approximation and idealization.  Specifically, I am wondering if anyone has seen some work on the following.  In the semantics of programming languages we find Domains as a place to talk about iteration and approximation.  We can define a Scott Topology on the Domain and now our Domain-maps are continuous maps.  Next,we can see our Domains as categories and turn the continuous Domain-maps  into continuous functors.  If we push the idea further, we have continuous functors and a notion of approximation which is now over categories.  Lambek ponders the existence of *the* category of Sets.  What about *approximations* to the category of sets.  For that matter, what might it look like to approximate any well-known category like that of manifolds or FDVec?
  I realize the question is vague.  I wish I had a more concrete question, but my grasp of the material is too weak.
  Naturally, any thoughts on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Here is the paper which outlines all of my ideas on using continuous functors in physics.


http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~bsprot1/EvolvingUniverseFeb24.pdf

I realize this is not the place to post this, but some of the posters here might find it of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, I just saw a paper about this very subject today -- Martin Hyland's ["Some Reaons for Generalizing Domain Theory"](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~martin/Research/Publications/2010/srfg10.pdf), which is concerned with precisely the generalization you suggest, in order to clarify the semantics of concurrency. This paper was apparently inspired by some work by Cattani and Winskel, but I found their work to be more categorically sophisticated than I could easily digest, and this one to be at about the level I can presently cope with.

EDIT: I also found a paper by Winskel in which he discusses the intuitions underlying his ideas, ["Events, Causality, and Symmetry"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.6016&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This seems quite accessible to me.

Comment: Thank you!  In fact, these thoughts are coming from my contact with concurrency and distributed systems. To put a point on it, consider a bunch of computers, connected by the internet and thus not sharing a universal clock, and they want to consider themselves as part of a group G.  G is a set which contains the names of all the computers.  However, agreement is generally untenable in these kinds of asynchronous systems.  Thus the concept of a single universe of sets for all these computers is also untenable. Perhaps they can approximate it much like the approximations in agreement protocols.